# I want to get the values in header of the table using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a html page where i create a table, and in that table i can drag and drop any element. Now i want to add some validation on table based on the values dropped in header. This is my html page.

```
<div id="table" ng-controller="dictionaryElementsController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                <div ondrop="angular.element(document.getElementById('table')).scope().drop(event)"
                     ondragover="angular.element(document.getElementById('table')).scope().allowDrop(event)">
                    <strong style="color: black;">(I)</strong>&lt;enter data&gt;
                </div>
            </th>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Now is there any way to find out that the value drop is in th, tr or td.? So that i can put validations according to the value dropped in th.

Comment: You should give https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop a try. Your way will probably lead you down a rabbit hole.